# "3d" карусель на slick slider

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js, carousel

Всем привет! 
Столкнулась с проблемой реализации вот такого слайдера, используя Slick Slider.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот (ссылка на JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/fqurka8y/1/) что получается у меня на данный момент. Проблема в том, что боковые слайды обрезаются, а должны помещаться полностью (как на картинке). Я пробовала увеличивать расстояния с помощью centerPadding до нужного, но тогда по бокам вылазят следующие слайды.
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как-то ее уже решал? 
Буду очень благодарна любому совету!

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: true,
  centerMode: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerPadding: '250px',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  speed: 500,
  dots: false,
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  background: pink;
}
.content {
  width: 975px;
  margin: auto;
}
.slick-slide:not(.slick-center) {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
.slick-active.slick-center+.slick-slide+.slick-slide {
  z-index: 1;
}
.slick-active.slick-center+.slick-slide,
.slick-center+.slick-cloned {
  z-index: 2;
}
.slick-center {
  z-index: 3;
}
.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 80ms;
}
.slider__item img {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834100/v834100491/58296/G8F9vgI_pr4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834100/v834100491/58296/G8F9vgI_pr4.jpg" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c834100/v834100491/58296/G8F9vgI_pr4.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Эй привет! Знаю, вопрос ты задавала очень давно. Но вот я на днях тоже мучался с этим и я нашел приемлемое решение, конечно надо еще допилить, но у меня все работает найс, вот копирую как есть.

```js
var rev = $('.rev_slider');
rev.on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  var
    cur = $(slick.$slides[slick.currentSlide]),
    next = cur.next(),
    prev = cur.prev();
  prev.addClass('slick-sprev');
  next.addClass('slick-snext');
  cur.removeClass('slick-snext').removeClass('slick-sprev');
  slick.$prev = prev;
  slick.$next = next;
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  console.log('beforeChange');
  var
    cur = $(slick.$slides[nextSlide]);
  console.log(slick.$prev, slick.$next);
  slick.$prev.removeClass('slick-sprev');
  slick.$next.removeClass('slick-snext');
  next = cur.next(),
    prev = cur.prev();
  prev.prev();
  prev.next();
  prev.addClass('slick-sprev');
  next.addClass('slick-snext');
  slick.$prev = prev;
  slick.$next = next;
  cur.removeClass('slick-next').removeClass('slick-sprev');
});

rev.slick({
  speed: 1000,
  arrows: true,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  prevArrow: '<button> prev</button>',
  nextArrow: '<button> next</button>',
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesPerRow: 1,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  centerPadding: '0',
  swipe: true,
  customPaging: function(slider, i) {
    return '';
  },
  /*infinite: false,*/
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.slick-slider {
  margin-left: -12%;
  margin-right: -12%;
}

.slick-list {
  padding-top: 10%!important;
  padding-bottom: 10%!important;
  padding-left: 15%!important;
  padding-right: 15%!important;
}

.slick-dots {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slick-track {
  max-width: 100%!important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)!important;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.slick-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%!important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.slick-snext,
.slick-sprev {
  display: block;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 20px);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slick-snext {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-sprev {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0px);
}

.test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #c00;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="rev_slider">
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rev_slide">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный пример не работает, мне нужен такой же слайдер, если не очень трудно сделайте пожалуйста пример  на сервисе из разряда codepen.io или поправте выложенные файлы

Comment: Пофиксил, теперь работает. Вместо .test вставьте свои слайды. и поправьте размеры под свои нужды

Comment: Автор вопроса, поставь галочку, не оставляй вопрос открытым

Answer (score 0):

Можно скрыть лишние слайды:

```
.slick-slide[aria-hidden="true"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```